# Windows Service Fails to Start. Event Log States "registry file is still in use"

Tags: .net, windows-services, nlog

After making minor changes to a Windows Service and deploying those changes to Production Staging (Windows Server 2008), the Windows Service fails to start.

The event log states only

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards.

One of the changes was to an NLog configuration file entry that only applies with Production build settings thanks to the magic of [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was an illegal NLog configuration setting in the Production NLog configuration.

NLog did not write any diagnostics to the Event Log.  Running the service in console mode (I use a pattern for services that checks for a /console flag to run as a console app rather than as a service), a useful Exception was thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'My.Service' threw an exception.
NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception occurred when loading configuration from C:\MyService\NLog.config 
---> System.NotSupportedException: Parameter levels not supported on FileTarget
```

**Lesson learned**: If a Windows Service that uses NLog fails to start without a meaningful EventLog entry, double-check the NLog configuration.

*Shared [Q&A style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) hoping this saves someone the 15 minutes it took me to sort out.*